# Limit of a sequence computed from another limit

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

So, I have been reading a calculus book where they are finding the
limit of a sequence $(\dfrac{n!}{2^n})_{n=1}^\infty$. This is how it is solved:

We know from previous example that for $n \geq 9$, $n! > 4^n$.So,

$\dfrac{n!}{2^n} > \dfrac{4^n}{2^n} = 2^n$

Since $\lim_{n \to \infty} 2^n = \infty$, we conclude that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{n!}{2^n} = \infty$.

Now, I can understand all the parts of the solution except the last
one. How it's getting concluded from $\lim_{n \to \infty} 2^n$, the
limit of $\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{n!}{2^n}$.

Answer (score 1):

If something tends to infinity everything larger than it tends to infinity.